# Implement State Monad transformer in Haskell from scratch

Tags: haskell, monads

When I was studying [Monad Transformer](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers), I decided to create `StateT s m a` from scratch with instances for `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad`.

This is what I have:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: (s -> m (a, s)) }

instance Functor m => Functor (StateT s m) where
    -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> StateT s m a -> StateT s m b
    -- which is (a -> b) -> (s -> m (a, s)) -> (s -> m (b, s))
    f `fmap` (StateT x) = StateT $ \ s -> fmap run (x s)
        where run (a, s) = (f a, s)

instance Monad m => Applicative (StateT s m) where
    -- pure :: a -> StateT s m a
    pure a = StateT $ \ s -> pure (a, s)
    -- <*> :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    -- which is StateT s m (a -> b) -> StateT s m a -> State s m b
    k <*> x = StateT $ \ s -> do    
        (f, s1) <- runStateT k s -- :: m ((a -> b), s)
        (a, s2) <- runStateT x s1
        return (f a, s2)

instance (Monad m) => Monad (StateT s m) where
    return a = StateT $ \ s -> return (a, s)
    -- >>= :: StateT s m a -> (a -> StateT s m b) -> StateT s m b
    (StateT x) >>= f = StateT $ \ s -> do
        (v, s') <- x s
        runStateT (f v) s'
```

My original intention is to implement `Functor (StateT s m)` with `Functor m` restriction, `Applicative (StateT s m)` with `Applicative m` restriction, and `Monad (StateT s m) with`Monad m) restriction. However I couldn't do the `Applicative` case and had to use `Monad m` restriction instead. Is there a way to do it with `Applicative m`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is correct. The additional comments are also welcome. I would write `<*>` without `runState`, but that's personal preference.

Keep in mind that you've re-implementend `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict.StateT`. For the lazy variant `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT`, you would have to use lazy pattern matches in several places, so I assume you wanted to implement the strict variant.

To answer your question: no, we cannot implement `Applicative (StateT s m)` in terms of `Applicative m`. A [Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18673525/1139697) contains some hints, but let's reiterate them:

Suppose you have two values `f`, `x` and want `y` with the following types:

```
f :: StateT m s (a -> b)
x :: StateT m s a
y :: StateT m s b
```

We first remove the newtype:

```
f :: s -> m (s, (a -> b))
x :: s -> m (s, a)
y :: s -> m (s, b)
```

If our initial state is `p`, we have

```
f p :: m (s, (a -> b))
x   :: s -> m (s, a)
```

We want to use the `s` from `f p` in `x` to feed into `x` and the function to use the `a`. Now, let's suppose that `m` is an Applicative. This gives us only `pure`, `fmap` and `<*>` to work with. Let's try to write an expression that only uses those three functions`pure`, `fmap` and `<*>`:

```
z s = fmap (\(s', f') -> fmap (\(s'', x') -> (s'', f' x')) x s') (f s)
```

Let's check whether that implementation is sane. It's easier to deciper if we swap `fmap`'s arguments:

```
x ~~> f = fmap f x
z s = f s                                   --  1
      ~~> (\(s', f') ->                     --  2
           x s'                             --  3
           ~~> (\(s'', x') -> (s'', f' x')  --  4
         )
```

1. We run `f s` to get our new state and our function.
2. Both are in `m`, so we use `fmap` to get in there.
3. We run `x s'` to get our new state again and our value.
4. Both are in `m`, so we use `fmap` yet again. However, we're using `fmap` **inside** `fmap`, which already tells us that we're not going to end up with a simple `m ...`.

In (4), we end up with the correct new state `s''` and the correct value `f' x'`. However, our type is `s -> m (m (s, b))`. Applicative does not provide any methods to reduce the number of `m`'s, so we're stuck. We need to use `join :: Monad m => m (m x) -> m x`.

If we go back, we see that the problem arises due to `x`'s type `s -> m (s, a)`. If it was `m (s -> (s, a))`, we could simply use `Applicative`. [Petr provides a detailed answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18676062/1139697).